# ARFoundation detecting vertical planes and placing objects - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

Im finding it difficult to find information for detecting vertical planes and putting objects on walls.

I see alot about AR Core and using the HelloAR example app, but i get loads of compile errors as im mainly building the app for iOS, although i will do it for Android to at some point.

Although i dont mind editing C# I cant actually read/write c# so the simpler the resource/answer the better.

I also wouldnt mind been able to design/change the detector image thing, the thing that shows up when it detects a surface.

On the horizontal one theres just a simple square/crosshair and i love that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARFoundation 1.0.0 preview 22 will surface the ability to select your plane detection mode: horizontal, vertical, or both. To use this mode, you will have to upgrade to the newly released Unity 2018.3: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/12/13/introducing-unity-2018-3/

For more about plane detection in ARFoundation, refer the following link

[AR Plane Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@2.1/manual/plane-manager.html)